# For H={A in V | A transpose = A} and V= M2x2, the 2-by-2 matrices with real entries, is H a subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra

To show a set is a subspace I know I need to show addition and scalar multiplication closure and the zero vector, but I'm not sure how using matrices.

Comment: $2 \times 2$ matrices that are equal to their transpose have the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}$ for $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$.  Take two matrices of this form and add them. Does the result have the same form?  Do the same for scalar multiplication.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem (setup and goal) you want help with, and use the occasion to provide *context* for your interest in the problem (why is it important or difficult for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the restriction to $2\times 2$ matrices is a bit of a red herring. You *could* prove this problem by directly considering the special structure of the entries of a $2\times 2$ matrix, but here it turns out that coming from abstraction is actually a bit easier.

Here's what I mean. We have two properties about the matrix transpose we care about. First, if $A$ is a matrix and $\alpha$ is a number, then $(\alpha \cdot A)^T = \alpha \cdot (A^T)$, which means that the transpose respects scaling. Second, if we have two matrices $A$ and $B$, then $(A + B)^T = A^T + B^T$. This means adding first and then flipping is the same as flipping first and then adding. These are important properties for your question.

Let $H$ be the set of matrices $A$ that satisfy $A^T = A$. To see that $H$ is a subspace, we simply need to check that

1. the zero matrix is in $H$;
2. if $A$ and $B$ are in $H$, then so is $A+B$;
3. if $A$ is in $H$ and $\alpha$ is a number, then $\alpha \cdot A$ is also in $H$.

Can you use the properties I suggested to finish the argument?

Answer (score 1):

To be a subspace it must be closed under scalar multiplication and addition.

For $A,B\in H$ and $\alpha\in\Bbb R$, we have:

$(A+B)^t=A^t+B^t=A+B$.

And $(\alpha A)^t=\alpha A^t=\alpha A$.

Conclusion?